# HTML/CSS rendering issue

Tags: html, css

I have a simple example of an issue I ran upon. Note the two divs each has 5 buttons which should render at 20% width each. The first set goes beyond the bound and am not sure why. If you use the dev tools you can see that the div itself is the right size of 100% width. In the second set when the buttons are concatenated it works. Can anyone explain this?

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdeMU/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav5 {
            white-space: nowrap;
         }
         .nav5 button {
             height: 50px;
             width: 20%;
         }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>
    <div class="nav5">
        <button>A</button>
        <button>B</button>
        <button>C</button>
        <button>D</button>
        <button>E</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav5">
        <button>A</button><button>B</button><button>C</button><button>D</button><button>E</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For questions like this you will benefit from using JSFiddle to show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can 'float:left' your buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/AdeMU/1/

```
    .nav5 {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .nav5 button {
        height: 50px;
        width: 20%;
        margin:0;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have specified `white-space: nowrap;` it collapses all the whitespaces into one, so it does not remove it entirely. You can use the second method you have specified or comment out the space in between.